# Sorting CSV data in JS object

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I need some help sorting 1370 rows of CSV data with JS! I am using the d3 library to create a data visualization.

The CSV is here: https://github.com/nickrinaldi88/BreitBart_DataVis/blob/main/breitbartData.csv

**My project**:

I have a csv file with 3 columns, Date, Word, and Count.

Essentially, I want to have 10 different arrays of objects for each unique word *(there are 10 unique words)* like so:

```
var Obama = [{date: 'the date', count: 72}, {date: 'the date', count: 41}]
var Trump = [{date: 'the date', count: 568}, {date: 'the date', count: 92}]
```

For each word, there are 136 rows of data, which means ideally I want each array to contain 136 objects corresponding to the date and count attributes that exist.

Should I utilize the d3.nest function?

I find myself trying to create the arrays dynamically in a loop but I'm having difficulty getting the result I want. A push in the right direction would help.

Thanks!

Comment: You have two May 8ths in the CSV for many of the words, do you want to sum when there are duplicate rows for a given name? Or is that an issue in the data?

Comment: Ah, good find. I think its supposed to May 7th, so I manually changed it. There will also be some dates that skip, early on in May. This is because I had a script that collected this data, and it was not running those days.

Comment: My question wasn't completely answered. I'll just select one of the responses. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach with vanilla JavaScript.

**Disclaimer** This is a pretty expensive approach and with a bit of effort could be optimized for performance.

First fetch the data...

**then** start by processing the CSV:

1. Split the CSV string (split)
2. Remove the header (slice)
3. Filter out the final, empty string (filter)
4. Iterate the array of strings to create an array of arrays (map)

```js
function processCSV(csv){
  return csv.split("\r\n").slice(1).filter(c=>c).map(d=>d.split(','));
}
```

**then** find the unique words:

1. Use a Set to ensure only unique values
2. Iterate the data to pull out the unique words and add to the Set
3. Return array of unique words and the data

```js
function findUniqueWords(data){
  const words = new Set(); 
  data.forEach(d=>{
    words.add(d[1]);
  });
  return [Array.from(words), data];
}
```

**then** create the required formatted arrays of objects:

- Iterate the unique words

  - filter the data for only the records that include that word
  - Iterate those records to create the desired format

```js
function createArrays(args) {
  const [words,data] = [...args];
  return words.map(w=>{
    return data.filter(record=>record[1] === w).map(fd=>{
      return {[w]:{date:fd[0], count: fd[2]}};
    });
  }).flat();
}
```

**then** Do something with the output

Here is the complete code. This code will not run here due to CORS restrictions.

```js
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nickrinaldi88/BreitBart_DataVis/main/breitbartData.csv')
.then(res=>res.text())
.then(processCSV)
.then(findUniqueWords)
.then(createArrays)
.then(console.log);

function processCSV(csv){
  return csv.split("\r\n").slice(1).filter(c=>c).map(d=>d.split(','));
}

function findUniqueWords(data){
  const words = new Set(); 
  data.forEach(d=>{
    words.add(d[1]);
  });
  return [Array.from(words), data];
}

function createArrays(args) {
  const [words,data] = [...args];
  return words.map(w=>{
    return data.filter(record=>record[1] === w).map(fd=>{
      return {[w]:{date:fd[0], count: fd[2]}};
    });
  }).flat();
}
```

Finally, here is a repl to demonstrate the outcome:

https://repl.it/@randycasburn/AlertPoorCodes